# Emulate symlinks and use them in PHPstorm

Tags: windows, unix, phpstorm, symlink

## Please help me to resolve the problem

### My project is:

```
->folder1
--->modules
----->Module1
----->Module2
->folder2
--->modules
----->Module3
----->Module4
```

The following structure I have on my LEMP virtual box. There are symlinks for modules from `folder2/modules` and on linux I have

```
->folder1
--->modules
----->Module1
----->Module2
----->Module3_symlink
----->Module4_symlink
```

And everything is executing well.

### The problem is:

I'm trying to setup IDE PHPStorm on windows7. I downloaded all code on local machine. xDebug is working properly, but there are two issues:

1. `folder1/lib` contains some xsl schemas, which are necessary for spelling for `folder2/lib`. On one hand - I can just copy these schemas into 2nd folder and put them into .gitignore. But on the other hand I have one more problem:
2. I'm trying to execute PHPunit tests for classes from `folder2`. But I faced with the same problems as in point one.

### My question is: is there any possibility in windows / phpstorm to emulate symlinks? Or somehow resolve this problem without installation unix system.

Thanks for all responses I've achieved it with command mklink

---

I've created symlink but PHPstorm think that it's independent folder. PHPStorm is trying to synchronize it. And git is showing this folder in untracked files.
Probably you can answer: synchronization with ftp will not bring harm. Folder can be added to gitignore.

But, is there another way? Please advice how properly achieve this.

Comment: ntfs support symlinks...

Comment: Junctions? I believe Windows 7 even supports creating junctions without that tool, but anyway, this works fine: [junction](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx). Yep, looked it up... MKLINK is the command under Windows 7.

Comment: Windows (Vista+) supports symlinks (files and folders); NTFS since Windows 2000 (or XP) supports Junction Points (can be applied to folders only). Have a look at **Link Shell Extension** -- very handy tool: http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'll check 'em all, when I get the office. I use win7

Comment: I successfully created symlink, but I've faced with another troubles. Please read my update after line. Here is copy: I've created symlink but PHPstorm think that it's independent folder. PHPStorm is trying to synchronize it. And git is showing this folder in untracked files. Probably you can answer: synchronization with ftp will not bring harm. Folder can be added to gitignore. But, is there another way? Please advice how properly achieve this.